# Trying to make it so when clicking Item in ListVIew, marker in map will show its infowindow

Tags: android, google-maps, marker, listviewitem

What I am Trying to do

[image]

When click on the item in listview, I would like to allow the Marker to act as it has been clicked, but I cannot seems to find solutions to this problem.

There seems to be no way to programmatically clicked a marker.

Is there any others solutions? The best I can think of is to create new marker and just let overlap the current marker.

Comment: you can save your marker along with  the objects on list view then on item click get that marker object and call this desiredMarker.showInfoWindow();  as @dev8080 answered below

Answer (score 0):

You need not simulate marker onclick event at all. Just add infowindow-opening code to your list item on-click event :

```
desiredMarker.showInfoWindow();
```